# ffmpeg Node Screen recording does not have audio

Tags: ffmpeg, electron, fluent-ffmpeg

I am building a screen recording application using fluent-ffmpeg.

```
let command = ffmpeg({ source: '1:0' })
command.inputFormat('avfoundation')
command.fps(60)
command.videoCodec('libx264')
command.audioBitrate('320k')
command.audioCodec('libmp3lame')
command.addOption('-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p')
command.save('output.mp4')
```

I am able to record the screen, but the audio of the screen is not being recorded. For example: When I play a YouTube clip and record my screen, the video will be there but the audio from the YouTube clip not.

Am I missing an option in ffmpeg? I cant get the screen audio (I am not talking about a microphone).

Edit: I want to use ffmpeg instead of Electrons `desktopCapture` as ffmpeg has more options and is more powerful.

Comment: Did you know Electron has screen capture built-in? See [desktopCapture](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer) for more information.

Comment: Yes, I know it, but I still wanted to use ffmpeg as its more powerful and has more advanced options.

Comment: Is audio device #0 a loopback device? What does `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""` return? In Windows (`-f dshow`) I had to install an extra driver to expose the loopback device. I suspect device #0 is a mic.

Comment: Remove `command.audioCodec('libmp3lame')` and check.